# Why hostname of docker embedded DNS does not work?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am trying to check if postgres container is accessible form within another container across the bridge docker network.

---

```
# /!\ Remove all containers /!\
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -aq)
```

---

### Launch database

```
docker run --name    db                     \
           --env     POSTGRES_PASSWORD=asdf \
           --detach  postgres:alpine
```

---

### Test connection with IP

```
IP=`docker network inspect bridge | grep IPv4 | grep -o -P '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'`; \
docker run --env IP=$IP alpine sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache netcat-openbsd && nc -zv $IP 5432"
```

leads to:

```
Connection to 172.17.0.2 5432 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Working!

---

### Test connection with hostname

```
docker run alpine sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache netcat-openbsd && nc -zv db 5432"
```

leads to:

```
nc: getaddrinfo for host "db" port 5432: Name does not resolve
```

Not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

**1. Create a "link" between the two containers over the default bridge network.**

```
docker run --name db --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=asdf --detach postgres:alpine
docker run --link db alpine sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache netcat-openbsd && nc -zv db 5432"
```

**2. Use a custom bridge network.**

```
docker network create --driver bridge postgres-network
docker run --name db --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=asdf --detach --network postgres-network postgres:alpine
docker run --network postgres-network alpine sh -c "apk add --update --no-cache netcat-openbsd && nc -zv db 5432"
```

Both solutions give:

```
Connection to db (192.168.128.2) 5432 port [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!
```

Note that the default bridge network is not recommended for production as explained in the [Docker networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/), so solution #2 is better.

If you use `docker-compose` instead of plain `docker` commands to run your containers, a custom bridge network is created automatically for each `docker-compose.yml`.